# SQL: update column counter and insert new row

Tags: sql, transactions

I have two tables (this is a very simplified model of my use case):

```
- TableCounter with 2 columns: idEntry, counter
- TableObject with 1 column : idEntry , seq (with the pair idEntry/seq unique)
```

I need to be able in 1 transaction to:

```
- increase counter for idEntry = x
- insert (x,new_counter_value) in the TableObject.
```

knowing that I must not lose any sequence, and it is a transaction highly concurrent and called a lot.

How would you write such a transaction in a statement (not for a stored procedure)? Would you lock the row of TableCounter for idEntry = x?

So far, I have this, but I look for a better solution.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT counter FROM TableCounter WHERE idEntry=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE TableCounter SET counter=counter+1 WHERE idEntry=1;
INSERT INTO TableObject(idEntry, seq) SELECT  TableCounter.idEntry, TableCounter.counter FROM TableCounter WHERE  TableCounter.idEntry = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Thank you

Comment: You would do this in a trigger.

Comment: this needs to be SQL db agnostic, so I need an SQL statement for this

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? the `select for update` is useless. Just run the `update` directly, that will also lock the row.

Comment: likely to be postgresql, but may be switched to another one - hence needs to be generic if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select for update` is useless if the next thing you do is to update the row anyway (this is true for any DBMS that supports `select for update`)

For Postgres this can be done in a single statement using a data modifying CTE:

```
with updated as (
  update tablecounter 
     set counter = counter + 1
  where identry = 1
  returning identry, counter
)
insert into tableobject (identry, seq)
select identry, counter
from updated;
```

The update will lock the row, which means that any concurrent insert/update (for the same `identry`) will have to wait until the above is committed or rolled back.

---

If I (really) needed a gapless sequence and I could live with the scalability issues of such a solution (because the requirement is more important then performance or scalability) I would probably put that into a function. Something like the following:

Define the sequence (=counter) table

```
create table gapless_sequence 
(
   entity text not null primary key,
   sequence_value integer not null default 0
);

-- "create" a new sequence
insert into gapless_sequence (entity) values ('some_table');
commit;
```

Now create a function that claims a new value

```
create function next_value(p_entity text)
  returns integer
as
$$
  update gapless_sequence
     set sequence_value = sequence_value + 1
  where entity = p_entity
  returning sequence_value;
$$
language sql;
```

Same as above: the transaction that acquires the next sequence for an entity will block all subsequent calls to the function for the same entity, until the first transaction is committed (or rolled back).

Now defining a table that uses the gapless sequence is quite easy:

```
create table some_table
(
   id integer primary key default next_value('some_table'),
   some_column text
);
```

And then you simply do:

```
insert into some_table (some_column) values ('foo');
```

A concurrent insert into `some_table` would wait until the first transaction commits. The `update` will then see the committed value and return the appropriate next sequence value.

Of course this can also be done without using a `default` clause in the table definition, but then you would need to call the function explicitly in the insert statement:

```
insert into some_table 
  (id, some_column) 
values 
 (next_value('some_table'), 'foo');
```

However that has the potential pitfall that nothing forces you to use the correct entity name when calling the function.

---

All the examples above assume that auto commit is turned **off**

Comment: assuming you also want scalability, what would therefore be the optimal solution to create a gapless sequence, if you knew for sure the dbms is postgresql and you can use any of its feature?

Comment: You can't have gapless sequences **and** scalable, concurrent inserts. You need to decide what's more important. The question is: why do you think you need a gapless sequence? The only reason I know are legal requirements e.g. invoice numbers **have** to be gapless in most countries.